# How to signin using Phone in Firebase and link FirebaseAuth object with the auth table getting the UID from Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to make a Firebase Android Project that make signup and login operations. During signup i stored the password and the phone number in firebase Database.
I wanted to login with the same information, how could i link my Auth table and my database using the UID from Database.

Comment: What do you mean by "Auth Table"?

Comment: Can you not just use Firebase Auth?

Comment: Simply FirebaseAuth. or a table that contains an Auth information, Example:- UID, phoneno, Signin date...

Comment: it is not possible to use FirebaseAuth to make login with phone number without sending verification code...'i think'